# Links not working after css3 animation in safari+chrome

Tags: html, css, webkit, anchor, css-animations

I have a link wrapped around two divs which are animated on :hover. In Firefox the link works fine and jumps to the right anchor. But in Safari and Chrome the links only work if the first of the two divs inside the < a>-element is clicked.

```
<li>
<a href="#work" class="inaktiv">
<div class="work1">a</div>
<div class="work2">b</div>        
</a>
</li>
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/26HgM/6/

Could anyone tell me why it is not working properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're rotating the `<a>` so it's facing backwards which webkit is interpreting as no longer being a link that can be interacted with.

One thing you could do is instead of rotating the link itself, add a container div inside the link and rotate that.

http://jsfiddle.net/26HgM/6/

Comment: The other thing is the :hover can't be on the thing that rotates. That's why I had the selector as .inaktiv:hover .container { transform: rotateY(-90deg); }

Comment: This is working for me in chrome as far as I can tell http://jsfiddle.net/26HgM/9/

Comment: Thumbs up! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<a>` is an inline element, while `<div>` is a block-level element. Inline elements cannot contain block-level elements according to the HTML standard, but browsers try to do it anyway--so we get buggy implementations. You will have to:

- put the links inside the divs, and have two links, or
- make the container a div and make it clickable with Javascript

Here's more on block-level vs inline: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm

Comment: a tag is inline-block in html5